# Finding the polynomial with roots equal to the square of the roots of another polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let's consider the polynomial:
$$a_{0}x^{n}+a_{1}x^{n-1}+a_{2}x^{n-2}+...a_{n-1}x+a_{n}=0 ...(i)$$
if $A$ solves $(i)$ i.e.
$$a_{0}A^{n}+a_{1}A^{n-1}+a_{2}A^{n-2}+...a_{n-1}A+a_{n}=0$$
then $A^{2}$ should solve the following polynomial:
$$b_{0}x^{n}+b_{1}x^{n-1}+b_{2}x^{n-2}+...+b_{n-1}x+b_{n}=0 ...(ii)$$
i.e.
$$b_{0}A^{2n}+b_{1}A^{2(n-1)}+b_{2}A^{2(n-2)}+...+b_{n-1}A^{2}+b_{n}=0$$

Is there a way to find the coefficients $b_{0}$ through $b_{n}$. I tried squaring $(i)$ but there were cross terms in the resulting expression which did not fit $(ii)$.

As an example take $x^{2}-7x+12$ whose roots are $4$ and $3$. Then the polynomial whose roots are $4^{2}=16$ and $3^{2}=9$ is $x^{2}-25x+144$

Comment: Your title asks for the new polynomial to have roots which are the square of the roots of the original polynomial. Is that what you mean? If so then the degree of the new polynomial will also be $n$ are there are still only $n$ roots. If you meant something else - "square roots" maybe? - please edit the question.

Comment: I mean finding coefficients of $(ii)$ specifically

Comment: You have not answered my question.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am assuming the OP meant square roots in my answer.

Comment: @GReyes Yes, but if the OP does mean that then the question must be edited. The comment on your question and the answer to my first comment here suggest that the OP is totally confused.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Agree.

Comment: I hope the meaning is now clear from the example in the edit.

Comment: Given a polynomial $a(x)$, it seems you are looking for the polynomial $b(x)$ whose roots are the squares of the roots of $a(x)$.  If so, then note that these are related as $b(x) = (-1)^n \cdot a(\sqrt x)\cdot a(-\sqrt x)$.  Does that help?

Comment: @Macavity It seems reasonable. But the $(-1)^{n}$ is strange.

Comment: That sign preserves monic polynomials, can be ignored otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Just take
$$
a_0x^{2n}+a_1x^{2(n-1)}+\dots +a_{n-1}x^2+a_n=0.
$$
if $a$ is a root of your polynomial, then $x=\pm\sqrt{a}$ are  roots of the one above.

Comment: A little clarification. $x$ should not be changed. what you have done is change $x$ to $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. I changed $x$ by $y^2$ so the resulting polynomial in $y$ has roots which are the square roots of the original ones. Just keep the coefficients in front of monomials with even powers $2,4,\dots 2n$.